# Linearly generated embedding?

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $\mathscr L$ a line bundle on $X$. Its section ring,
$$
R(X,\mathscr L) = \bigoplus _{n=0}^\infty H^0(X,\mathscr L^{\otimes n}),
$$
is a finitely generated graded $H^0(X,\mathscr O_X)\simeq k$-algebra.

I wonder if the following condition has an established name:

Assume that $\mathscr L$ is very ample and let $\phi:X\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^N$ denote the  embedding induced by the global sections of $\mathscr L$. So, in particular the map 
$$
H^0(X,\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^N}(1))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathscr L) \tag{$\star$}
$$ 
is surjective. Further assume that

\begin{equation}
\text{$R(X,\mathscr L)$ is generated in degree $1$,} \tag{$\star\star$}
\end{equation}

that is, by the elements of $H^0(X,\mathscr L)$. In particular, then the embedding $\phi$ is projectively normal, but this is a stronger condition.

I would like to say something like "$\phi$ is *blah*, when this holds", so the question is:
**Q:** Does this property/condition have an established name in the literature?

If not, I would probably say that "$\phi$ is a *linearly generated embedding* if this condition holds". My rationale for that name is that by $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$ it follows that $R(X,\mathscr L)$ is the homogenous coordinate ring of $X$ corresponding to the embedding $\phi$
and  that $R(X,\mathscr L)$ is generated by the images of linear functions on $\mathbb P^N$.

An ideal answer would give a reference (or more) where this is defined/used, or in absence of a reference would either support the name I am suggesting or argue against it and in that case would suggest an alternative.

Comment: Sándor, a quick (dumb) question.  Is there an easy example where this is a stronger condition than projectively normal (lets assume that $X$ is a normal variety itself)?  

In particular, if $X$ is projectively normal, then I thought all the

$$H^0(\mathbb{P}^N, O_{\mathbb{P}^N}(i)) \to H^0(X, L(i))$$

maps are surjective (Hartshorne, II, Ex 5.14)?  Doesn't that imply that $R(X, L)$ is generated in degree $1$, since $R({\mathbb{P}^N}, O(1))$ is generated in degree $1$ and we now have a surjection between the two algebras?

Or is the point you want a name for non-normal schemes/varieties?

Comment: Karl, you are perfectly right! The situation I have is somewhat more complicated and in order to make it reasonable I simplified the situation to a point that it lost the juice. I will have to think about the more general situation, but this is certainly a good point. Thanks! Why don't you post this as an answer, so I can accept it and with that close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This was a comment originally.*

The generation in degree 1 is the same as projective normality at least for normal varieties.

For simplicity, assume that $X$ is normal.
By Hartshorne, Chapter II, Exercise 5.14, we know that if $X$ is projectively normal (with embedding associated to the complete linear system of $L$), then
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}^N, O_{\mathbb{P}^N}(i)) \to H^0(X, L^i)
$$
is surjective for all $i$.  Therefore $R(X, L)$ is a quotient of $R(\mathbb{P}^N, O(1)) = S$.  But $S$ is generated in degree $1$, and so $R(X,L)$ is generated in degree $1$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about "linearly/projectively normal and normally generated" or "linearly/projectively normal and $N_0$"?

Mumford in "Varieties defined by quadratic equations" defines $X$ to be normally generated if the section ring is generated in degree $1$. Green and Lazarsfeld in "On the projective normality of complete linear series on an algebraic curve" call the same condition $N_0$.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I will check these out. Your suggestion sounds reasonable based on these references, but it's a bit long. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Also, I would like a name for the embedding, not for the section ring being generated in degree $1$. I understand that this is a tiny difference, but still...